# How to download and display a text file using HTML5/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, emc

Is there anyway to download a text file and display its contents using HTML5/JavaScript?  I'd prefer to save it to a memory location, but saving it to a temporary file would be a second option.

-- Updated --

As per the statement below.  Here's what I've got so far using AngularJS acquiring a file from an Atmos ObjectStore.  It's not clear to me how to present the file contents.

```
var app = angular.module('MyTutorialApp',[]);

app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http) {

    console.log("starting download");
    $scope.downloadedFile = null;

    var config = {headers:  {
        'Accept': '*/*'
    }};

    $http.get('https://some_path/theFile.txt?uid=myUUID&expires=1396648771&signature=mySignature', config)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.downloadedFile = data;
            console.info(data);
            console.log("finished download");
        });
});
```

Comment: You probably want an AJAX request.

Comment: What technology are you using in the back-end?

Comment: A very useful tool for this is Node.JS.  At github, you can find the project "learnyounode" and they have a Http client example that does exactly that.  Plus, the project has a boatload of other fun examples to play with.

Comment: First you said `download` (and we know what that means), than you say `display contents` ... Decide what you want, show what you tried, be more specific.

Comment: Also what is for you a `memory location`?

Comment: 'memory location' = not saved to disk.  I'm hoping to avoid prompting the user to save the files somewhere, then have to navigate to it again to re-acquire it for display on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with HTML5 + Javascript! I've made **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/w33Fg/)**:

HTML code:

```
<input id="myFile" type="file" value="Select a text file" />
<br />
<h3>Results:</h3>
<div id="myContents"></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$("#myFile").on("change", function(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $("#myContents").html(this.result.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
    };
    reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
});
```

EDIT:

You've edited your question, and now I see you want to take the TXT file from your server. Well, I don't use Angular.JS, but in jQuery, it would be something like:

HTML:

```
<div id="myServerContents"></div>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myFile.txt",
    data: {},
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        $("#myServerContents").html(response.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
    },
    dataType: "text/plain"
});
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I saw you've edited your question, and you'd like to take a file inside your server. So, you'll need to use AJAX, or websockets to take the contents you'd like to. I'll make another example, one minute =)

Comment: I've just edited my answer including the AJAX request for a txt file, and how you should put it in your HTML.

Comment: Thank-you Businas.  I added the .ajax and it runs and appears to download the file (Content-Length:27741).  I'm not clear on how to present the response in the HTML body.  I tried "<div id="myServerContents"></div>" but that did not work.

Comment: Have you tried to see if the AJAX response is coming with data? Are you calling an TXT file inside your domain or is it cross-domain? (because if you're trying to get information from another domain, it won't work due to security reasons)

Comment: I'm not sure how to verify if I am receiving the file itself.  The content length returned is 27741 and the actual file I am acquiring is 28K on disk, so it looks like its sent back.  Plus the response code is http 200.

Comment: Turns out is was a issue with CORS support.  I'll mark this as the solution since I know it works and more closely matches what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Fetching txt file content from a client side could be done in many ways, one would be to use JQuery [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/), but I'm not sure if you use JQuery.

Another simple option is to use iframe, take this example:

```
<iframe src='http://yourSite.com/yourDir/logs/myTextFile.txt' />
```

<kbd>[JSFIDDLE DMEO](http://jsfiddle.net/szQj7/3/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank-you Joraid.  That did download the file, but I get prompted to save the file.  how do I get the contents to display within the frame?

Comment: hmmm ideally it should just display the txt file content within the fram, lemme check.

Comment: @TERACytE kindly check my answer update, I've added a demo. Test and see if you can view the txt file content or you are being promoted to download. Btw, I noticed you are using angulerjs, are using JQuery along the side?

Comment: I'm not getting prompted for a download, but I see "An error has been encountered in accessing this page." in the lower right pane.  I'm not using jQuery, but I can.

Comment: I'm very sorry, the sample file I chose was wrong, it was an inaccessible file. Here, check this, http://jsfiddle.net/szQj7/2/ this is updated with a normal .txt file. Btw, you can use your own text file, just change the src in the IFrame tag to really test if it will load your file or not.

Comment: Your example works.  I tried the same with my file and I still get the prompt to save it locally.  I wonder if the my FireFox browser is interfering in some way.

Comment: That's strange. I don't get that prompt neither on Firefox *using 27.0.1* nor Chrome. Any chance that you have a download accelerator plugin which interferes with the iframe maybe? Give another browser a try and see how it goes. IFrame is like having a mini page inside the main page, it has nothing to do with download.

Comment: I have no download accelerator installed.  I ran the code in Safari and Chrome.  Both automatically downloaded the file, and did not display it in the iFrame.  I'm on Mac OS v10.9.2.

Comment: try the jquery code at this page, **http://jsfiddle.net/szQj7/4/** Click Fetch button **but you will get an error!** I won't be able to do that on jsfiddle cuz Ajax can only access same domain. I've just tried it on my server and got result from the text file though.